# MSSQL How to aggregate row from query (not table)

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I need to aggregate row into string in this query:

```
WITH requery AS 
    (SELECT  CAST ( Name AS VARCHAR(1000) ) as Folder, f1.ParentFolderID, unt.NetworkName, unt.Model, Marker
    FROM    [Base].[dbo].[Folders] as f1
    JOIN (
        SELECT u.NetworkName, m.Name as Model, u.ParentFolderID, ma.Name as Marker
        FROM Base.dbo.Units as u
            JOIN Base.dbo.Models as m
            ON u.ModelID=m.ModelID
            LEFT JOIN Base.dbo.MarkerLinks as ml
            ON u.ParentFolderID=ml.FolderID
            LEFT JOIN Base.dbo.MarkerS as ma
            ON ml.MarkerID = ma.MarkerID
        WHERE u.NetworkName LIKE 'pcname'   ) as unt ON unt.ParentFolderID = f1.FolderID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CAST ( (f.Name + '\' + f2.Folder) AS VARCHAR(1000) ) as Name, f.ParentFolderID, f2.NetworkName, f2.Model, f2.Marker
    FROM    [Base].[dbo].[Folders] f
    JOIN    requery as f2
    ON      f.FolderID = f2.ParentFolderID)
SELECT  NetworkName,Model,Folder,Marker
FROM    requery
WHERE ParentFolderID is NULL
```

it return data as

1. pcname  model   location    user1
2. pcname  model   location    user2
3. pcname  model   location    user3

but I need

1. pcname  model   location    user1,user2,user3

I know about OUTER APPLY ([like there](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/191-String-Aggregation-in-PostgreSQL,-SQL-Server,-and-MySQL.html)) but I don't understand how to use it here. thanks.

Comment: You need to use XML for this. The article you referenced should work quite easily. Here is another article that explains this process from a purely sql server standpoint. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Answer (score 0):

I'm #$#$#, just used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) to last part of query and it's working!

```
SELECT  NetworkName,Model,Folder,Marker
FROM    requery
WHERE ParentFolderID is NULL
```

thanks 4 all and NiMa exclusively)